How to make Desktop the default file explorer location?
When I open a file explorer window it always opens to One Drive. How can I make it open to the Desktop by default instead?

How do you open File Explorer? The shortcut on your Taskbar or the Start Menu? The Command menu? Keyboard shortcuts? Different solutions may be needed based on how you open File Explorer.

You can make a shortcut to open explorer anywhere, e.g., C:\Windows\explorer.exe c:\Windows
